# Слежение 2д персонажа за курсором мыши

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытаюсь реализовать слежение 2Dперсонажа за курсором мыши, анимации переключаю с помощью паттерна State Machine в самом коде. Когда персонаж стоит, все работает исправно, но при движении возникает точка, в которой анимации меняются без перерыва. (Например, анимация вверх и влево(-0.7, 0.7))

Проблема возникает именно при движении персонажа, когда за ним следует камера.

У меня есть четыре направления анимаций:

- (1, 0) - вверх
- (-1, 0) - вниз
- (0, 1) - вправо
- (0, -1) - влево

Анимацию я меняю на ту, которая ближе к точке `((Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - _rigidbody.position).normalized`

Движение персонажа происходит через `_rigidbody.MovePosition()`

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class PlayerAnimationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<InfoAboutAnimation> _idleAnimations;
    [SerializeField] private List<InfoAboutAnimation> _walkAnimations;
    [SerializeField] private Animator _animator;
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
    private List<(Vector2 vector, Direction direction)> _directionCircle;
    private StateMachine _heroAnimationController;
    private IState _idleHeroState;
    private IState _walkHeroState;
    private void BuildDirectionCircle()
    {
        _directionCircle.Add((new Vector2(0, 1), Direction.Up));
        _directionCircle.Add((new Vector2(0, -1), Direction.Down));
        _directionCircle.Add((new Vector2(-1, 0), Direction.Left));
        _directionCircle.Add((new Vector2(1, 0), Direction.Right));
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _heroAnimationController = new StateMachine();
        _idleHeroState = new Idle(_animator);
        _walkHeroState = new Walk(_animator);
        _directionCircle = new List<(Vector2 vector, Direction direction)>();
        foreach (var e in _idleAnimations)
        {
            _idleHeroState = _idleHeroState.AddDirection(e.direction, e.clip);
        }
        foreach (var e in _walkAnimations)
        {
            _walkHeroState = _walkHeroState.AddDirection(e.direction, e.clip);
        }
        BuildDirectionCircle();
    }


    private Direction FindNearestDirection(Vector2 vec)
    {
        (Vector2 vector, Direction direction) ans = _directionCircle[0];
        foreach ((Vector2 vector, Direction direction) e in _directionCircle)
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(vec, e.vector) < Vector2.Distance(vec, ans.vector))
                ans = e;
        }
        return ans.direction;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        Vector2 direction = ((Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - _rigidbody.position).normalized;
        Debug.Log(direction);
        Direction viewDirection = FindNearestDirection(direction);
        Direction moveDirection = FindNearestDirection(movement);
        _walkHeroState.SetNormalDirection();
        if (movement != Vector2.zero)
        {
            //if (IsOppositeDirections(viewDirection, moveDirection))
            //{
            //    _walkHeroState.SetReverseDirection();
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    _walkHeroState.SetNormalDirection();
            //}
            _heroAnimationController.Initialize(_walkHeroState, viewDirection);
        }
        else
        {
            _heroAnimationController.Initialize(_idleHeroState, viewDirection);
        }
    }

    private bool IsOppositeDirections(Direction a, Direction b)
    {
        return (a == Direction.Left && b == Direction.Right) ||
               (a == Direction.Right && b == Direction.Left) ||
               (a == Direction.Up && b == Direction.Down) ||
               (a == Direction.Down && b == Direction.Up);
    }
}
```

Видео с проблемой: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PIKdfMWFNYT2e0MzmPmKLIC1xLADyWaC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Для чего в сравнении используется Vector2.Distance?

Comment: Я сравниваю хорды, для определения ближайшей точки. Я могу делать это как-то иначе?

Comment: Какой точки? Вам нужно же направление

Comment: Точки на круге указывают направление анимации, я пытаюсь определить к какой точке ближе мой вектор. Та точка, к которой он ближе является анимацией, которую стоит проиграть. Я понимаю, что я мог использовать вместо этого условия, но когда на круге появятся еще 4 точки, это может сильно все усложнить

Comment: (направлением анимации)

Comment: Код надо вставлять прямо в вопрос. На этот раз я помог оформить, на будущее учтите данный момент. Ссылка на сторонний ресурс с кодом может сломаться со временем, после чего ваш вопрос превратится в тыкву и станет бесполезен для будущих посетителей. Всё необходимое для ответа должно быть прямо в посте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас есть вектор направления от объекта на мышь (вероятно, direction), то отнормируйте его, разделив на его же длину (в unity наверняка есть функция вроде normalized). Затем посчитайте скалярные произведения этого вектора и единичных векторов направлений (в юнити Vector2.Dot). Наибольший результат - наиболее близкое совпадение направления

Comment: У минусатора есть возражения по сути?

Comment: Я не оценивал ваш голос. Я добавил видео с проблемой и понимаю, так находить ближайшую точку как вы, будет более правильно, но это не решило мою проблему. Код теперь выглядит слудующим образом: https://pastebin.com/r1Xb8E52

Comment: @Igor Wilson Для просмотра видео нужно разрешение "You need access"

Comment: Теперь все должно быть нормально

Comment: Хм.. А вы можете выводить direction для контроля?

Comment: да, это происходит на (-0.7; 0.7).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XhP8iooK5r4CF1SbLHKqvdDcH9tm0uER/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ну так это 45 градусов, как раз разделительное значение. Можно ввести гистерезис, чтобы не было метаний туда-сюда

Comment: Порой, я тупее, чем думаю. Спасибо @MBo, проблема решена не без вашей помощи